# php replace in url path

Tags: php, replace, path

Здравствуйте, как заменить параметры в url path?
Есть адрес:

> http://site.com/param1/param2/param3?a=1&b=2&c=3

Как заменить например `param2` на `hello`, при этом чтобы всё что после `?` осталось на месте.
При этом хотелось бы использовать [`http_build_url`](https://github.com/jakeasmith/http_build_url/blob/master/src/http_build_url.php).

Примерный каркас функции:

```
@params — входные параметры для замены param2 => hello
function replace_path($params = array()) {
    return http_build_url();
}
```

Comment: если у вас есть массив строк и замен, то самый простой способ -  использовать `str_replace`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов

```
<?php

$str = 'http://site.com/param1/param2/param3?a=1&b=2&c=3';

echo replace('param2', 'hello', $str);
// http://site.com/param1/hello/param3?a=1&b=2&c=3

/**
* 
* @param str $patt Искомое значение
* @param str $repl Значение для замены
* @param str $str  Строка для поиска
* 
* @return str 
*/
function replace($patt, $repl, $str) {
    return preg_replace('~'. preg_quote($patt, '~') .'~', $repl, $str);
}
```

---

Или так

```
<?php

$str = 'http://site.com/param1/param2/param3?a=1&b=2&c=3';
$repl = ['param2' => 'hello'];

echo replace($str, $repl);
// http://site.com/param1/hello/param3?a=1&b=2&c=3

/**
* 
* @param str $str Строка для поиска
* @param arr $arr Массив для поиска и замены
* 
* @return str
*/
function replace($str, $arr) {
    return strtr($str, $arr);
}
```